# Does std::function have virtual functions for copying and moving?

Tags: c++, std

If we store `std::functions`s in a vector, and it needs to resize and reallocate the copy constructors or the move constructors for `std::function` will be called. Generally speaking lambdas and functors hold trivially moveable and destructible objects, but in the case that it captures something non trivially destructible or trivially movable or copyable then it needs to have a vtable on how to do these operations, right?

Here is an example of std::function being able to take any callable object, the std::function must have function pointers or virtual functions to move, copy and destroy the object correctly, right?

```
    struct CustomFunctor
    {
        
        std::vector<int> buffer;
        CustomFunctor() {}
        
        

int operator()() { return 7; }
};

int main()
{
    
    std::function<void(void)> f{ CustomFunctor() }; /* NEEDS TO CALL CUSTOM DESTRUCTOR AND COPY AND MOVE FUNCTIONS */

    f = []() { return 7; };
    /* IF IT CALLS DESTRUCTOR OR MOVE AND COPY FUNCTIONS BASED ON TEMPLATE
                                                  THERE'S TROUBLE, RIGHT?*/
}
```

Comment: https://youtu.be/tbUCHifyT24

Comment: AFAIK std::function is always designed with a vtable. I don't see a way for it to work without it.

Comment: _"...then it needs to have a vtable..."_ no `std::function` is a templated class without a virtual destructor [func.wrap.func.general](https://eel.is/c++draft/func.wrap.func.general#lib:function)  Could you expand the question with a small example that illustrates the issue please.

Comment: The function class itself may not have a virtual destructor, but it needs to have a pointer either to a destructor or its own vtable with the destructor  function defined the specific type it holds. There's no way you could assign arbitrary objects to it and have it destroy and move the objects correctly, as far as I know. Check the example I added to the question.

Answer (score 3):

`std::function` does not, technically speaking, have virtual member functions. GCC's implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/std_function.h) in case you want to see all the nitty-gritty details for yourself. It certainly doesn't have a vtable; instead, it uses a pair of function pointers - one for invoking the function, and one for managing the object (destruction, copying, moving). These function pointers are specific for the type of callable that's currently stored in the function object; therefore, the functions they point to know what the underlying callable type is.

These two function pointers get populated by the constructor of `std::function`, which has access to the exact type of callable being assigned to the function object. Therefore it can instantiate appropriate function templates (invoker and manager functions) and place pointers to these functions in the function object.

In summary, `std::function` is typically implemented something like this. (This is most likely not fully accurate, but it should get the general idea across.)

```cpp
enum class ManagerOp {
  DESTROY,
  COPY_ASSIGN_TO,
  MOVE_ASSIGN_TO
};

template<typename Callable, typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct function_callable_implementation {
  static Ret invoker_function(not_std_function *self, Args...) { /* call it */ }
  static void manager_function(not_std_function *self, not_std_function *other, ManagerOp op) {
    switch (op) {
      case DESTROY: /* destroy the callable */ break;
      case COPY_ASSIGN_TO: /* copy the callable */ break;
      case MOVE_ASSIGN_TO: /* move the callable */ break;
      default: /* unreachable */
    }
  }
}


template<typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct not_std_function {
  using InvokerType = Ret (*)(not_std_function *self, Args...);
  using ManagerType = void (*) (not_std_function *self, not_std_function *other, ManagerOp op);
  
  InvokerType m_invoker = nullptr;
  ManagerType m_manager = nullptr;
  
  union {
    void *m_callableInstance;
    char m_smallTypeOptimizationBuffer[IMPLEMENTATION_DEFINED_BUT_PROBABLY_16_BYTES];
  }
  
  ~not_std_function() {
    if (m_manager) m_manager(this, nullptr, ManagerOp::DESTROY);
  }
  
  not_std_function& operator= (const not_std_function& other) {
    if (this == &other) return *this;
    
    if (m_manager) m_manager(this, nullptr, ManagerOp::DESTROY);
    if (other.m_manager) other.m_manager((not_std_function *)&other, this, ManagerOp::COPY_ASSIGN_TO);
    
    return *this;
  }
  
  /* same thing for move assign, copy construct, move construct */
  
  not_std_function(auto callable) {
    using Stuff = function_callable_implementation<decltype(callable), Ret, Args...>;
    
    m_invoker = &Stuff::invoker_function;
    m_manager = &Stuff::manager_function;
    
    /* initialize m_callableInstance or m_smallTypeOptimizationBuffer */
  }
};
```

This kind of implementation ensures that there will be no issues with slicing; it's a nice value type that can be copied, stored in vectors, etc without having to worry about virtual functions.

As another example, here's [a `std::any`-like class that can be used as the key to a map](https://gist.github.com/JoniSt/22b8710d7d698c5cb441a501ce0382df). It uses the same "trick" of holding a set of function pointers to achieve type erasure without compromising type-safety. Compared to `std::function`, my `ttlhacker::any_key` implementation uses one additional level of indirection, though.

Comment: I'm probably being stubborn, but there must be either function pointers or a vtable. At "case DESTROY: /* destroy the callable*/ How on earth is it going to call the proper destructor when absolutely any callable (provided the return type and arguments of the operator( ) match can be stored and is managed by the class? The same thing goes for copying and moving, it needs pointers to know what it's copying and moving. So either it has three different pointers (one for each move, copy and destructor), or probably better a vtable (an extra indirection) so that you're not storing 3 pointers...

Comment: over and over again. In my opinion having the switch statement is probably a bad idea, as it needs the function pointers anyway, so it may just call them directly and avoid going through the switch statement.

Comment: Note that ```struct function_callable_implementation``` is *templated on the callable*. It knows the actual type. There is one ```manager_function``` etc *per callable type* that gets stored in a ```std::function``` so the correct destructor etc can be called. The actual implementation works exactly that way. Note also that indirecting through a vtable is MUCH slower than a switch/case. The actual destructor / copy assignment / move assignment will be inlined into ```manager_function```; there is no additional indirection. Just a single function that deletes/copies/moves a specific type.

Comment: Doesn't the speed of a switch statement depend on what the compiler does exactly with it? For example if there are only 3 cases it may be faster for it use if-else statements. However if it uses a jump table, it would need to, supposing the spread of integer cases is wide, use a hashing system, unless mapped the integers into an array (the jump table), but this would only be ideal if the case integer range/spread is low. Do you get what I mean?

Comment: No sane compiler is going to generate a jump table here, they all generate a few (three pairs of) cmp/je instructions. The CPU will predict these with almost 100% accuracy based on branch history ("if I reach this code via this path, that jump will be taken" - yes, CPUs do that). In the end, you'll have one indirect jump followed by a very predictable conditional (direct) branch. The other alternative - a vtable-like implementation - would need to jump to a location loaded from memory, which is pretty much the worst thing you can do to a modern CPU's pipeline, apart from self-modifying code.

Comment: Thanks. At worst with the vtable it's one more function call through a pointer, so you're comparing a switch statement to that. With just 3 x 8 = 24 bytes for function pointers (if you store the desctructor, copy and move pointers separately) you reduce the whole thing to just function call through a pointer (that has to be done in the above implementation anyway), but without the switch statement. But if the switch statement is as fast as you say then that's not even necessary.